# java - Is there a way to get pattern of a given date string Or from a LocalDate

Tags: java, datetime-format

I have a LocalDate object but i am struggling to find the pattern programatically using the DateTimeFormatter class in Java 8.  Is there a way to do it or any 3rd party library for this?

I have tried the following but I do not want to use DateFormat class as this is not recommended.

```
LocalDateTime.parse("8/22/19 4:39 PM").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern1).withLocale(Locale.getDefault()))
```

"Prints this which is what i kind of want -> M/d/yy h:mm a (I really want 'mm/dd/yyyy h:mm')

Although if i try that above pattern string to parse a date string it fails. Gives me this excepton"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '8/22/19 4:39 PM' could not be parsed at index 0
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
```

"The reason I want this behaviour is that there are locale specific date patterns configured in our i18n file. In case those are unavailable(Not configured) I need to supply with the jdk locale/zone specific date pattern. The DateFormat class kind of gives me but not exactly"

Comment: You say you have a LocalDate object so why do you want to parse a string then? Note that a LocalDate (or Date) doesn't have a format, you select the format when you want to convert the date object to a string.

Comment: There are locale specific date patterns configured in our i18n file.  In case those are unavailable(Not configured) I need to supply with the jdk locale/zone specific date pattern.  The DateTimeFormatter kind of gives me but not exactly. see above.

Comment: To get exactly the pattern you want then you supply it yourself (why trying to get something that is only "kind of right" anyway?). See my answer below or look at retrieving the current locale and use that.

Comment: Are you suggesting to have all the predefined formats by country and access them by locale?

Comment: I was under the impression you wanted one format, maybe you should clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using DateTimeFormatter converting from and to String. Note that I use LocalDateTime rather than LocalDate since time is included as well.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterWithTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy h:mm a").withLocale(Locale.US);

String outWithTime = formatterWithTime.format(LocalDateTime.now());
System.out.println(outWithTime);

String in = "08/22/19 4:39 PM";
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.from(formatterWithTime.parse(in));
System.out.println(ldt);
```

This prints

> 08/23/19 10:44 AM
>   2019-08-22T16:39

Comment: Sorry but this is not what i want.  I do not want to supply the pattern.  Its the otherway round.  I want to find out the pattern from a given LocalDateTime.

Comment: LocalDateTime doesn’t have a pattern so it cannot be done